# Bad parameter when using save() on Image

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am having a bit of trouble with saving an Image, it says "Bad paremeter" on the line where I try and save the image.

I'm not sure if it's how I am creating the image or if it's just saving that's the problem.

```
public static void Fullscreen()
{
    string fileName = Helper.RandomStr(10) + ".png";

    try
    {
        var image = ScreenCapture.CaptureFullscreen();
        image.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to capture fullscreen because: " + ex.ToString() + "\r\n\r\nFile: " + fileName);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is the method that gets the Bitmap

```
    public static Bitmap CaptureFullscreen()
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ScreenDimensions.Width, ScreenDimensions.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
            }

            return bmp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does Helper.RandomStr(10) do? Is a valid path in `filename`?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049122/how-to-capture-the-screen-shot-using-net

Comment: You have to document what `ScreenCapture.CaptureFullscreen` is.

Comment: Have you tried to give an defined Point variable to "CopyFromScreen" method. E.g. CopyFromScreen(new Point(0,0),new Point(800,600),bmp.Size) ?

Comment: Don't dispose the bitmap before returning it from your method.  That is supposed to go bang!

Comment: Hans, that was the reason why it wasn't working. I figured it out before I saw this but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bad parameter is the way GDI+ tells that there was some problem.
Its a shame that the errors are not very much descriptive.

First try to wrap image parameter to Bitmap constructor like:

```
image = new Bitmap(image);
```

This forces to process the bitmap immediately.

**It was even simpler, remove using on the bitmap.**

Answer (score 0):

Try using a known path and see if starts working. If so then you might want a new random string generator that makes valid paths or a different way of naming the file.