# .Net : executing external program and get its screen diplay

Tags: c#, .net

I can execute an external console program using c# and getting its outputs thanks to `System.Diagnostics.Process` class.

Is there any way to execute an external program witch is not a console program, and get its outputs ?

Suppose we have some "program.exe", suppose it's a 2D game for example. Is it possible to get the video stream from it? In an array of pixels, for example.

Comment: Is it possible to grab the output of another? Certainly, otherwise programs such as Fraps, X-Split, Camtasia, and similar game and software grabbing systems wouldn't work. Now, they usually only work with DirectX, but I've seen similar things for other programs, so it's possible.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen so using directX I can grab video outputs from a program, thats good. I suppose I can then easily redirect this outputs.

Comment: From games, yes, but probably not from normal Windows applications. But there are programs out there that does it. So obviously it is possible. However, I would imagine many of them have to go pretty low level in order to do it, so I'm not entirely sure you can do it in .NET alone.

Comment: Windows or any other O.S. must store the screen buffer of a service somewhere, I think the key is here. And yes, this is so low level.

Comment: Is your external program is API you are working on ? Does it expose the video stream to you as controller or something like that ? Do you have access to the HWnd ?

Comment: @ilansch no i suppose the external program is a black box. but i can get the hwnd using `System.Diagnostics.Process` with the "Handle" propriety.

Comment: @ilansch suppose i have a handler to this program, where windows stores its screen ? it must be somewhere in the memory.

Comment: Maybe you can host that hwnd inside your application ? I know we hosted a Win32 hwnd in our WPF application, we took the pointer to handler, and used hwndsource and hwndhost classes

Comment: @ilansch thanks mate, this is a beginning of a solution. ill read about this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. 
Start the process with the Process class. 
You'll have to know the name of the window you want to capture.
Then use win32 api (pinvoked) FindWindow, GetWindowDC, .. to get a bitmap at regular interval.
this approach is explained here:
http://www.nullskull.com/q/10087766/capturewindow-in-cnet-20-windows-application.aspx

Another approach is to capture a rectangle of the screen,
[Capture the screen shot using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049122/capture-the-screen-shot-using-net)
you can get the bounding rectangle of a window using the win32 api GetWindowRect

Comment: Yeah mate, this is a golden answer thanks a lot, im gonna dive into this, ill be back as soon as i can write a proper code.