# Getting information from curson position in Minesweeper

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if there is a way for me to extract some information from a cursor position in C#.

I'm trying to create a minesweeper solver and would like for the mouse to hover over the windows version of Minesweeper and be able to tell the amount of bombs surrounding a square by looking at the color of the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture a bitmap of the screen using the code provided in answers to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049122/capture-the-screen-shot-using-net) but you'll then have to process that yourself to derive any meaning from it.

Comment: I would also capture the mouse's location (P/Invoke) and take advantage of that information while processing.

Answer (score -1):

Getting cursor location using Windows API:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public static implicit operator Point(POINT point)
    {
        return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
    }
}

POINT lpPoint;
// Get current location of cursor
GetCursorPos( out lpPoint );
```