# C# Get pixels behind transparent control

Tags: c#, pixel

I am building an application that is able to get the pixels of pixels of a part of your screen. I am trying to do this by making the background of a form transparent, so that you can see through the form. The problem is, is that when I use the PanelToBitmap function I am getting the transparent color, instead of the pixels which are actually visible to the user.

Currently I'm using this.

```
Point point = new Point();

if (point.X > this.Location.X && point.X < this.Location.X + this.Width && point.Y > this.Location.Y + RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle).Top - this.Top && point.Y < this.Location.Y + this.Height)
{
    point.X = point.X - this.Location.X;
    point.Y = point.Y - this.Location.Y;
    Bitmap img = (Bitmap)PanelToBitmap(this);
    Color color = img.GetPixel(point.X, point.Y);
    form.label1.Text = color.R.ToString();
    form.label2.Text = color.G.ToString();
    form.label3.Text = color.B.ToString();
}
```

Is there any function that is able to get the pixels that are actually visible to the user? I was thinking about the GetPixel function in the Gdi32 library, although people say it's slow.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

```
Graphics.CopyFromSreen(..);
```

Create an `Image`, copy pixels from screen using `Graphics.CopyFromSreen`. Then you can use `bitmap.GetPixel()` to get the color at `pixel`

Refer [Graphics.CopyFromSreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen.aspx) for more info

Comment: It seems to be working, although for some reason this doesn't capture all windows. For example the color picker in paint.net doesn't get captured. Any ideas on why this could be?

Comment: Am afraid, It should work for all windows. May be it miss wpf elements? but not sure:)

Comment: CopyFromScreen() has a bug.  You'll need [this workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072580/17034).