# C# Stream Desktop Activity

Tags: c#, .net

To keep things simple, I decided to follow this approach. Server when launched and clicked on the Start button, captures desktop every sec and saves an image file. Client when launched and clicked on the View Desktop button, reads the image into a picturebox every 500 millisec.

But I've a problem displaying image in the Client form. It displays the initial image but not any other subsequent images, just stays still.

I've tried Refresh() and Invalidate() but nothing works. Can you guys help me solve this

### Server Code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;

namespace SMSServer
{
    public partial class SMSServerForm : Form
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer txtTimer;
        private CaptureDesktop cd;
        public SMSServerForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           cd = new CaptureDesktop();
           txtTimer  = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
           txtTimer.Elapsed += txtTimer_Elapsed;
           txtTimer.Enabled = true;                      
        }

        private void txtTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            cd.CaptureDesktopAsImage();
        }        
    }
}
```

Client Code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using System.Drawing;

namespace SMSClient
{
    public partial class SMSClientForm : Form
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer txtReadTimer;
        public SMSClientForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void txtReadTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            desktopPictureBox.Invalidate();
            desktopPictureBox.Image =  Image.FromFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\CurrentImage.png");
        }

        private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtReadTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
            txtReadTimer.Elapsed += txtReadTimer_Elapsed;
            txtReadTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

To capture desktop, I've used the method described here:
[Capture desktop C# including semitransparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072349/capture-screenshot-including-semitransparent-windows-in-net/3072580#3072580)

Comment: add  CaptureDesktopAsImage(); code

Comment: It is mentioned at the end of my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image.FromFile() locks the file, so your capture program is probably not able to update it on disk. [Open Image from file, then release lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576341/open-image-from-file-then-release-lock)

Here's some code that can be used to read a file and convert it to Image without locking the file. [How to convert image in byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-in-byte-array/16576471#16576471)

See in particular the bit at the end where I write:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = GetImageFromByteArray(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
```

Comment: the first link, making use of the using() statement fixed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try the method [PictureBox.Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) (inherited from Control) after you updated the image.

Comment: In your example code you call Invalidate before you update the image path.