# C# screenshot bug?

Tags: c#, screenshot

I use the following code to take a screenshot:

```
var rc = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.CopyFromScreen(rc.Left, rc.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

Now this works wonderfully and it's easy to work with, however I always come across little 'white dots' in some of the screenshots. This can be very annoying and distort the image when it occurs in larger quantities.

I managed to narrow down the issue and when I try to take a screenshot of the following image the bug occurs:

[image: bug-causing image]

The output of the screenshot looks like this:

[image: bug]

How can you fix this?
And out of curiosity, how is this explained?

In my testing environment the screenshot isn't saved at all. I directly use it with the following code:

```
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

tl;dr I'm trying to take screenshots and some of the pixels are replaced with white and distort the result.

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: It turns out that the bitmap makes the area transparent (white comes from the background color of the form, thanks for spotting this spender!)

[image: bug with different background]

But obviously as you can clearly see in the first picture; I'm not trying to capture any transparent content. Why does it do this?

EDIT2:

This is the whole class I'm using to select my screenshot:

```
public partial class SnippingTool : Form
{
    public static Image Snip()
    {
        var rc = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen;

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.CopyFromScreen(rc.Left, rc.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

        var snipper = new SnippingTool(bmp);

        if (snipper.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return snipper.Image;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public SnippingTool(Image screenShot)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackgroundImage = screenShot;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

        int screenLeft = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left;
        int screenTop = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top;
        int screenWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
        int screenHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;

        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(screenLeft, screenTop);


        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    public Image Image { get; set; }

    private Rectangle rcSelect = new Rectangle();
    private Point pntStart;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
        pntStart = e.Location;
        rcSelect = new Rectangle(e.Location, new Size(0, 0));
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
        int x1 = Math.Min(e.X, pntStart.X);
        int y1 = Math.Min(e.Y, pntStart.Y);
        int x2 = Math.Max(e.X, pntStart.X);
        int y2 = Math.Max(e.Y, pntStart.Y);
        rcSelect = new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rcSelect.Width <= 0 || rcSelect.Height <= 0) return;
        Image = new Bitmap(rcSelect.Width, rcSelect.Height);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(Image))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(this.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height),
                rcSelect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, Color.Black)))
        {
            int x1 = rcSelect.X; int x2 = rcSelect.X + rcSelect.Width;
            int y1 = rcSelect.Y; int y2 = rcSelect.Y + rcSelect.Height;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(0, 0, x1, this.Height));
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(x2, 0, this.Width - x2, this.Height));
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(x1, 0, x2 - x1, y1));
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(x1, y2, x2 - x1, this.Height - y2));
        }
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rcSelect);
        }
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape) this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

On my form I then go:

```
pictureBox1.Image = SnippingTool.Snip();
```

Comment: Are you saving as PNG? It looks like you are. Try saving as JPG

Comment: How is the file being saved?

Comment: Does this involve video players?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I've added more information on this in the post.

Comment: Just so I am clear, you are trying to take a screenshot of a black screen but when generated it's white?

Comment: This rather looks like the captured image has transparency. Supposing the background color of `pictureBox1` was set to black?

Comment: In a way, yes. Although if you look closely you can see that it is a dark shade within an even darker shade. I think it's the combination that causes the bug.

Comment: What exactly is the screenshot of? Something GPU-accelerated like flash or video?

Comment: Just a simple image on Paint.

Comment: spender, you are definitely onto something! I just changed the background color of the form and the white has changed to that color. (Reference: http://i.imgur.com/zLOaLcM.png). But obviously the image I'm trying to take a picture of doesn't have any transparency in it. Why does it save it with transparency?

Comment: can you present code of how you draw your picture?

Comment: It looks to me like it is down to the `CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy`, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.copypixeloperation(v=vs.110).aspx), this will copy directly from the source so if the image you are copying has complete opacity then this will be copied... does changing this parameter help? (i.e `CopyPixelOperation.CaptureBlt`)

Comment: Changing it to that makes my screen go completely black.

Comment: On my form I then go: at which event of your form you do this?

Comment: Looks like a video driver bug to me, look for an update.  CopyFromScreen() is not entirely squeaky-clean either, you could try [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072580/17034).  But I doubt that's the issue here.

Comment: John, if you are able to (with gimp or something) create an image that has  different opacities in it and see how it looks when a screenshot is taken with your program.... did any of the other enumerations make a difference? the documentation uses `MergePaint`

Comment: Hans I tried the other code and it produces the exact same result.

Comment: I don't think it's a driver bug. I can reproduce the problem the same way

Comment: Definitely not a driver problem. I've had people on different machines confirm this bug.

Comment: @John: Try `new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);`

Comment: That does it! The bug is gone. What does this property do, exactly? Because it seems to have a major effect on the quality of the image, which is unfortunate. (Here's a Putin for reference: http://i.imgur.com/YyipZOt.png)

Comment: `CopyFromScreen` doesn't really work with anything but software surfaces. Anything drawn in Overlay mode will end up being "a window" into the overlain surface (that's why it's called "overlay" I guess). I assume that the new MSPaint exploits hardware accelerated drawing, which is not a "surface", and doesn't get captured by `CopyFromScreen`. You might remember trying to save video frames through MSPaint - and MSPaint showing you a moving video in the same spot. Saving that produces a black image, of course.

Comment: Interesting, that should have only gotten rid of the alpha part of the bitmap. Are you using some color scheme other than 32-bit? Or are you running in 16-bit color mode or something?

Comment: Nope, Windows is running in True Color (32 bit) mode. But the degrade in graphics is very noticeable. Putin isn't happy.

Comment: @John: Did you do it for both `Bitmap` creations? Play with `CopyPixelOperation.CaptureBlt` in combination too. Try `Format32bppRgb`or `Gdi` or `Canonical` too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this issue; this is the configuration that ended up working fine for me:

```
var rc = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen;

using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(rc.Left, rc.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
    }
    using (var snipper = new SnippingTool(bmp))
    {
        if (snipper.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return snipper.Image;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Note the [SnippingTool.Snip()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3124252/17034) helper method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that we were capturing the screen in ARGB, and the captured image would come with transparency.

Then we'd save it as a JPG, and the transparency would become white.

To solve the problem, we just need to instantiate the Bitmap with an explicit PixelFormat that does NOT include alpha:

```
Bitmap screenBmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
```